# Problems setting up dvwa

Tags: php

I am trying to set up Damn Vulnerable Web App (DVWA). I installed XAMPP for Linux from the apachefriends download page.

I tried to set up the database, but it shows "Could not connect to the database - please check the config file".

**config.inc.php** file shows:

```
$_DVWA[ 'db_server' ] = '127.0.0.1';
$_DVWA[ 'db_database' ] = 'dvwa';
$_DVWA[ 'db_user' ] = 'root';
$_DVWA[ 'db_password' ] = 'p@ssw0rd';
```

I replaced the password with blank. After making the password blank when I go to http://localhost/dvwa it takes me to the login page.

I tried with username as root and kept password as empty. It gives me an error login failed. How I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

### *** ***Create the DVWA configuration file*** ***

I suggest you doing this:

erase the file  dvwa which is in the directory **/var/www/html/dvwa/** and  copy it again in this directory

```
   cd /var/www/html

   sudo rm -rf dvwa/                 #to delete the file
```

Now go to the destination of your dvwa file that you downloaded
For example for me I put it in the Desktop

```
    cd Desktop

    sudo cp -r ./dvwa/ /var/www/html/dvwa/

    cd /var/www/html/dvwa/config/

    sudo cp config.inc.php.dist  config.inc.ph
```

So  **config.inc.php**  will be created and most importantly do not forget to check the passwords in this file (config.inc.php).